# Implementing RTOS on BeagleBone Blue

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, rtos

I have a few questions related to the BeagleBone Blue,

**Background:** I want to implement my own flight control scheme on this platform and for the same I wish to write the whole controller from scratch. I however do not wish to write the HAL again myself as I am not at all equipped to do so. So my questions are as follows:

1) I was told a RTOS is essential for a Flight Controller, is there any tutorial on how to install, implement and use an RTOS on the blue?

2) While implementing my own Flight Control Scheme by using ArduPilot libraries, will I need to use RTOS?

Any help is greatly appreciated as this is stalling my project in a major way!

Comment: If you need RT0S, take existing one, like Zephyr.

Comment: ...or ERIKA Enterprise: https://github.com/evidence/erika3